# Icons getting disappears if the text is too long in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-layout, android-jetpack-compose-row, android-compose-layout

```
@Composable
fun TopAppBar(
    name: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Row(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(20.dp, 0.dp),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
    ) {
        Icon(
            imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowBack,
            contentDescription = "Back",
            tint = Color.Black,
            modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp)
        )
        Text(
            text = name,
            overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            fontSize = 20.sp,
            maxLines = 1
        )

        Row {
            Icon(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_bell),
                contentDescription = null,
                tint = Color.Black,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(8.dp, 8.dp)
                    .size(24.dp)
            )
            Icon(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_dotmenu),
                contentDescription = null,
                tint = Color.Black,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(8.dp, 8.dp)
                    .size(24.dp)
            )
        }

    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You have to set the `weight` and the `fill` to `false`:

```
    Text(
        modifier = Modifier.weight(weight = 1f, fill = false),
        text = name,
        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
        fontSize = 20.sp,
        maxLines = 1
    )
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

You can add the **`weight`** modifier to the `Text` composable

```
Row(){
    Icon()
    Text(
        text = ".....",
        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
        fontSize = 20.sp,
        maxLines = 1,
        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
    )
    //...
}
```

[image].
[image]